# insert dateTimePicker into MySql phpmyadmin database

Tags: c#, mysql, datetimepicker

I want to insert date from dateTimePicker into mysql database in phpmyadmin, but when I click save mysql database date become 0000-00-00

here is my code

```
private void save2()
        {

            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < ((dataGridView1.Rows.Count) - 1); i++)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd2.Connection = cn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into lumugada.inventory(Nama_Product,Brand,Category,Deskripsi,Currency,Qty,Price,Total_Price,Nama_Supplier,Date,Remark) Values('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column8"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column9"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value + "','" + txtNs.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column12"].Value + "')";

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Clone();


                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            cn.Close();        
        }
```

what's wrong?
Can someone help please.

Comment: You should **always** use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Did you debug your code as well? What are your column types and what are your values? Why do you insert `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date` as a character to your `Date` column? If your `Date` column is a `datetime`, you need to insert your datetime value withour single quotes.

Comment: Also use `using` statement to dispose your `MySqlCommand` and  `MySqlConnection`. And if you use `i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count) - 1`, this doesn't read the last row of your datagridview since it is started as `i = 0`. I guess you should change it as `i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count)`

Comment: I'm using date types in my mysql date column

Comment: can you show me the right code?
I'm still new programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The string represantation of the date must be in a format that MySQL understands. That is: "YEAR-MONTH-DAY".

From the mysql manual

> "date parts must always be given in year-month-day order (for example, '98-09-04'), ".

[MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html)

You could string format the date to match the correct format

```
string.Format("{0:000}-{1:00}-{2:00}", date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
```

or you could use a parameterized query where you set a placeholder for the date *"@date"*
and then add the parameter to the query

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

using quotes in your command and adding the values like this has 2 main disadvantages:

- Your query is exposed to injection (as mentioned in the comment)
- For every value there is a cast to nvarchar type in sql

This means that every field that is not nvarchar my have an unappropriate cast to nvarchar. This goes for your `Datetime` field Date.

To get rid for both of these problems use parameters:

```
md.CommandText = "Insert into lumugada.inventory(Nama_Product,Brand,Category,Deskripsi,Currency,Qty,Price,Total_Price,Nama_Supplier,Date,Remark) Values(@Product,@Category,@Desk,@Currency,@Qty,@Price,@TotalPrice,@Supplier,@Date,@Remark)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product").Value=dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value ;
...
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

HAve in mind that the default `SqlDbType` is nvarchar so you have to specify it for those fields that are indeed nvarchar, however for `Date` field you have to set

```
SqlDbType.DateTime
```

Comment: Error 141 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\LUMUGADA\LUMUGADA\Purchase.cs 257 49 LUMUGADA